# Can't select vertices by right clicking in UV editor (2.7)

Tags: uv, selection-tools

I was working on a project, trying to texture a castle.  Everything was working as intended, but then suddenly, the UV editor started acting up. My cursor became a circle, the only way I can select vertices is by using Select -> Border select, and the hotkeys aren't working at all.

When I open another blender file, it works normally. Did I save the file with a wrong parameter or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have activated 'UV Sculpt'.
Disable it and you should be able to work normally again.
[image]